# Trying to call API through Apex with custom security certificate but getting CalloutException

Tags: apex, callout, security, certificates, api-client-certificate

I'm trying to use Apex to call some API endpoints to do some validation for my company. There are some specific properties of these APIs that make it a bit tricky:

- The APIs are hosted on self-deployed Kubernetes clusters, and have their own security certificates.
- These endpoints are not public right now and require a proxy to be running to hit them.

For other SDKs that we've validated, we've just had to specify the custom API endpoint and authenticate. Then, we could always do something like disabling SSL verification to get around the security issue.

Salesforce, as far as I can tell, does not allow you to do that. I've followed the instructions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232390&language=en_US&siteLang=en_us&type=1) to add the security certificate to my organization and the instructions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm) to set the certificate in my Apex code.

Beyond that, I've also made sure to add the API endpoint and proxy URL to the remote site settings.

With all that, I'm still getting the following error when trying to make an API call: `System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"`

Does anyone have any ideas what I might need to try next? I saw some things about whitelisting Salesforce IP addresses, so I'm asking around about that now. Other than that though, I'm at a loss on what to try next.

Comment: Can you try by whitelisting SF ip lists for now? https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003652

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm asking around about getting that done and then I'll report back if it works. Just trying to see if there's anything else I'm missing in my setup.

Comment: One thing to check is if it works after disabling SSL cert then its not IP whitelisting issue, cert is not installed properly in the 3rd party system

Comment: Is there a way to just disable SSL cert verification in Salesforce? I wasn't able to figure that out and would love to do that just for testing.

Comment: Ask 3rd party to disable it and use http instead of https

Comment: Salesforce requires SSL be enabled to connect with their servers using at least TLS ver 1.2. Do your proxy servers support TLS 1.2? If not, that could be at the root of your issue. You may also want to consider setting this up using Named Credentials, esp if you are doing mutual authentication.